# When and how exactly does @SpringBootTest scan?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test

How exactly does `@SpringBootTest` scan? My current understanding is this:

1. **If you pass a `@Configuration`**, it doesn't scan at all and is happy with that configuration class's beans
2. **If you don't pass any configuration or pass a `@TestConfiguration`**, it scans down (the test root) and then up (the source root) until it finds a `@SpringBootConfiguration` class (or `@SpringBootApplication` that incorporates it) and then scans down for "real" configuration classes (those marked with `@Configuration`) and takes their beans (both declared and scanned)

What actually happens?

Answer (score 2):

From my perspective, your understanding is quite close to how **@SpringBootTest** works in the Spring Framework, especially when focusing on how the application context is loaded and what beans are initialized.
This annotation is often used for integration tests and ensures that the Spring context is loaded, mimicking the behavior of an actual running Spring Boot application.

If you provide an explicit **@Configuration** class using the classes attribute of **@SpringBootTest**, then only that configuration is used, and no scanning occurs.
All the required beans must be defined within that configuration class.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = CustomConfiguration.class)
```

If you don't specify any **@Configuration** or **@TestConfiguration**, Spring will look for the primary configuration. It will scan upwards in the package structure starting from the package where your test class is defined until it finds a class annotated with **@SpringBootApplication**

```
@SpringBootTest
```

Once it locates the primary configuration, it will scan downwards from that point for all classes annotated with **@Configuration**, **@Component**, **@Service**, etc. and initialize the corresponding beans.

If you use **@TestConfiguration**, this is a special case. This annotation is used in conjunction with **@SpringBootTest** to define additional beans or to override existing beans for the test context only.

```
@TestConfiguration
public static class TestConfig {
    // some beans
}
```

When you use **@TestConfiguration**, Spring Boot still scans for the primary configuration in the manner described above. But the beans defined in **@TestConfiguration** will take precedence overriding any similarly named beans in the primary configuration.